# I tried vertical align. Can someone help me align my fiddle?

Tags: css

**I need the left and right side div blocks to be vertical align.** I tried the table vertical align method. I also tried web kit. Can someone help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/qmykegvb/1/

Overview.
I am trying to create a map of hotel. Each div represent a room. The divs has to be 100% width but keeps height ratio. This is what I done so far.

```
#i10
{ width: 11% ;
margin:0px;
overflow:hidden;
padding-bottom: 38%;
    }


#l1,#l2,#l3,#l4,#l5,#l6
{
width: 100% !important;
   padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

Comment: So is the issue the extra space underneath room #6 on each side?

Comment: the issue is that the left and right side height doesnt not equal to middle cell. I like to vertical align the cells on the right and left to solve this issue.

Comment: even if I make the cells the left and right cells to be bigger/smaller, when i change the window size, it does not equal to the big middle cell's height.

Comment: Seems like css property align-content should work, but I've failed to make it so.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-content.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#l1, #r1 {
    margin-top:8px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qmykegvb/3/

EDIT: You may have to find the right percentage margin so that the rooms adjust as you enlarge/reduce the width of the page.

Edit: Final solution: http://jsfiddle.net/qmykegvb/4/

Comment: It needs to be responsive to any window size. Please.

Comment: @TinCho This seems to be more responsive, unless you are planning to have the map under an inch wide. http://jsfiddle.net/qmykegvb/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
#element { display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle; /* or top, bottom */
}
```